# What is the bind-attr deprecation for href attribute that calls a function?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Ok I have a link tag that has a `bind-attr` to the `href` attribute. The attribute points to a link returned from a computed property in the application's controller. How is the deprecation applied here?

console error-->

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: An error occurred while setting up template bindings. Please check for invalid markup or bindings within HTML comments

Actual code (that works):

```
<a {{bind-attr href="computed_prop_name"}} target="_blank"> Some text</a>
```

I tried this:

```
<a href="{{computed_prop_name}}" target="_blank"> Some text</a>
```

In the application controller `computed_prop_name` is a computed property that checks a parameter and returns one of two links depending on the parameter.

```
func_name: function () {
  var url = isTrue ? "https://example.org/one":"https://example.org/two",
  return url + "/details";
}.property()
```

Comment: `<a href="{{href}}">Click me</a>`, where `href` is the computed property from the controller.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but that doesn't seem to work. When I do that, my entire template doesn't render at all

Comment: Please provide more bits of code, including the template and relevant parts of the controller. Do you see any console messages?

Comment: console message-->Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: An error occured while setting up template bindings. Please check for invalid markup or bindings within HTML comments.

Comment: Would you mind adding that error to the question itself, as well as the code bits as I mentioned.

Comment: Please show the code for `func_name`. Is it a function, or a computed property?

Comment: Please try `href={{func_name}}` (no quotes).

Comment: That didn't work either